# mysql jdbc : Communications link failure due to underlying exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i try to connect jee with mysql DB using jdbc , an error was shown :
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception
what is the problem ?? 
this is my test code

```
      try {
        connexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url,utilisateur,motDePasse);

        System.out.println("******succes********");

    } catch ( SQLException e ) {

            System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace

Comment: STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1997)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:573)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1044)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
 at

Comment: Please **edit** your question with that information, and what you posted is not the full stacktrace.